# Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Number

Tags: visualforce, character-encoding

I need to add a special character for a field on VF page and it's throwing an exception.

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Number

Can anyone help me with this, please?

```
<apex:outputText value="{! IF( ISBLANK(Quote.Total_Leasing_Costs__c), '-', '$'+Round(Quote.Total_Leasing_Costs__c,0)) }"/>+
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `TEXT()` function to convert the round value to text?  Also you have a plus sign at the end of the line, is that in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the `ROUND()` output within a `TEXT()` is what you need here. `+` in this context expects appending two string values whereas `ROUND()` returns a number and thus the error.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISBLANK(Quote.Total_Leasing_Costs__c), '-', 
                        '$' + TEXT(Round(Quote.Total_Leasing_Costs__c,0)))}"/>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad that it worked and that I was able to help.